# Is it a good practice to call Javascript code from server-side?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with some legacy Asp.Net MVC project where it is very common to find actions in some controllers that return javascript calls. For instance:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string code)
{
    var result = await _repository.CreateFromCode(code);
    if(result > 0)
        return JavaScript("DoSuccessLogic(" + result + ");");
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "Wrong code specified. Please enter a valid code");
        return PartialView(code);
    }
}
```

This idea of calling client code from the server, looks awkward to me, actually it smells like an anti-pattern. I assume that the System.Web.Mvc.JavaScript method was added to the MVC framework to handle very specific cases, but that it's usage is probably not much encouraged; especially in cases like this one where one could use the Json method instead and handle the aftermath of the action in client side entirely from an onSuccess handler or something similar.

However I'm not sure and don't have the arguments to convince others to change it.

So the questions are:

1. Is this really an anti-pattern that should be avoided?
2. If so, why?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to flip your question around - what advantage does this give and why keep it?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, i think it can be called anti-pattern

2) In general it **is not very good practise to use it widely.**

*JavaScript(...)* method returns *JavaScriptResult*. Really *JavaScriptResult* is just the same as a *ContentResult*, but 
*JavaScriptResult* is hardcoded to return content-type header *application/
x-javascript* in the response.

You should think about using *JavaScript(...)*  like about injecting SQL commands into your C# code, it’s an uncomfortable clash of technologies. I will try to describe pros and cons os such approach.

**pros**

- Allows to implement fastly small features (for example modify DOM) which don't require tons of JS code.

**cons**

- Makes code brittle
- Makes code unreadable
- When you create JS code by concatenation of C# strings,  you have no
  JS syntax highlighting
- Tightly couples your server-side code to your client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I would call it an anti-pattern. It seems like the function could be pushing something to the client but hard to tell from the snippet provided. There are circumstances where data is pushed to the client but I don't think it is typically done this way.

Some questions to answer that may help you determine the sustainability/maintainability of the code:

1. How can `DoSuccessLogic(...)` be tested?
2. What is `DoSuccessLogic(...)` doing that cannot be done in C#?
3. Is `DoSuccessLogic(...)` pushing something to the client?